# How to set popover view controller frame while it is already displayed in iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, frame, uipopovercontroller

I have view controller presented in form sheet, On button click popover gets presented, There is search bar in popover view controller, As started typing in search bar keypad gets appeared and as parent view controller is presented in form sheet shits towards top according to its default behavior ,So need to set frame of popover accordingly,  How to set popover's frame while it is already present?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I made a category on `UIViewController` a while back for this

UIViewController+PopOver.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController (PopOver)

- (void) forcePopoverSize;
- (void) forcePopoverSizeWithWidth:(float) width andHeight:(float) height;

@end
```

UIViewController+PopOver.m

```
#import "UIViewController+PopOver.h"

@implementation UIViewController (PopOver)

- (void) forcePopoverSize
{
    //    CGSize currentSetSizeForPopover = self.contentSizeForViewInPopover;
    CGSize currentSetSizeForPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0f, 330.0f);
    CGSize fakeMomentarySize = CGSizeMake(currentSetSizeForPopover.width - 1.0f, currentSetSizeForPopover.height - 1.0f);
    self.preferredContentSize = fakeMomentarySize;
    self.preferredContentSize = currentSetSizeForPopover;
}

- (void) forcePopoverSizeWithWidth:(float) width andHeight:(float) height
{
    //    CGSize currentSetSizeForPopover = self.contentSizeForViewInPopover;
    CGSize currentSetSizeForPopover = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    CGSize fakeMomentarySize = CGSizeMake(currentSetSizeForPopover.width - 1.0f, currentSetSizeForPopover.height - 1.0f);
    self.preferredContentSize = fakeMomentarySize;
    self.preferredContentSize = currentSetSizeForPopover;
}

@end
```

Then in your `UIViewController` you could just call `[self forcePopoverSizeWithWidth:752.0f andHeight:300.0f];` f.e.

Let me know if it works

Comment: contentSizeForViewInPopover this is deprecated method for ios 7, Is is ok to use deprecated methods?

Comment: I changed my answer to be in line with the new methods in iOS7, please try it now